# Comparing array value for each increasing input "ID"

Tags: javascript

I want to write a function that loops and compares the value of the array `answers` with each input (`type=text`) in a sheet increasing the ID's input. The following is the code  I wrote and it doesn't work. How I can rewrite it correctly?

```
function Correct()
{
  var answers=['X', 'XX', 'XXX', 'XXXX', 'V', 'VV', 'VVV'];
  var ids=['q1', 'q2', 'q3', 'q4', 'q5', 'q6', 'q7'];
  var i;
  var x;
  for (var i = 0; i < answers.length; i++)
  {
      for (var x = 0; x < ids.length; x++)
      {
          if(document.getElementById('+[x]+').value==answers[i])
              document.getElementById('+[x]+').style.backgroundColor='green';
          else
              document.getElementById('+[x]+').style.backgroundColor='red';
      }
  }  
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming that you want to access a DOM-Element with ids 'q1', 'q2',..., right?
then the error is in there:
document.getElementById('+[x]+')
it should be document.getElementById(ids[x]).value for example

Comment: Don't use Capitalized names in JS, it is a [convention in JS](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html#names) to only capitalize the names of [constructor functions](http://helephant.com/2008/09/14/constructor-functions/). If you use a linting program like [jsLint](http://www.jslint.com/) or [jsHint](http://jshint.com/), and you should, they use this convention to spot places where a constructor has been used without the `new` keyword. If you were to lint your code you would get warnings about not using `new` when you call `Correct` because the linter would mistake it for a constructor.

Comment: Thank for the comment! I will use these tools in the future. I'm learning from a bunch of sources (books, sites, tutorials, blogs and so on) and the patterns are difficult do understand in that mess...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
document.getElementById('+[x]+')
```

to

```
document.getElementById(ids[x])
```

and it should work!

But better 'find' the element only once, store it and then access it:

```
myInput = document.getElementById(ids[x]);
if(myInput.value==answers[i]){
    myInput.style.backgroundColor='green';
}
else {
    myInput.style.backgroundColor='red';
}
```

and get rid of the ; at the end of the if{}else{}

**Edit:**
To get the actual result you want to achieve you should do:

```
for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    myInput = document.getElementById(ids[i]);
    if(myInput.value==answers[i]){
        myInput.style.backgroundColor='green';
    }
    else {
        myInput.style.backgroundColor='red';
    }
}
```

Because you don't need to iterate through both arrays, since then you would compare EVERY question with EVERY answer. But in your case you only want to compare the matching answers.

A better data-structure therefor would be:

```
var questions = [
    {id: 1, question: "What is 1+2?", answer: "3"},
    {id: 2, question: "What is 1-2?", answer: "-1"},
    ....
    {id: 3, question: "What is 2+32?", answer: "5"}
];
// That would live somewhere in the <script> tags
```

if you then would build/construct your questions like that:

```
var html="";
for(i=0; i<questions.length; i++) {
    html+= questions[i].question + " <input id='q"+qustions[i].id+"'><br>";
}
// write those generated input fields somewhere suitable in your document
document.getElementById('myQuestionsOutputDiv').innerHTML = html;
```

and would check if correct answers are given like this:

```
function Correct() {

for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
    myInput = document.getElementById('q'+questions[i].id);
    if(myInput.value==questions[i].answers){
        myInput.style.backgroundColor='green';
    }
    else {
        myInput.style.backgroundColor='red';
    }
}

}
```

you'd end up in having less but reusable code.

Comment: Tanks a lot, Jeff!!! It's my first question (ever) because usually I do not know how to ask or what the problem is... Very very tanks!!

Comment: The answer makes sense but it only works with the last pair answer[i]/ids[x]... the others are considered incorrect and styled in red...

Comment: @DanielCenoz Yes, that's true. The reason is that you actually iterating through all the 'questions' 8 times. I'll edit the answer in a second so it makes sense for your needs!

Comment: it Works fine now. I tested... WOW I thought my problem was simple!!! Very tanks! I'm very impressed!